# Scientific notation for numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, coding-style

In my JavaScript code, I have large numbers (e.g. a billion).

Is there any problem with the following, cross browser:

```
var x = 1E9;
```

Or do I have to write it as:

```
var x = Math.pow(10, 9);
```

I prefer not to write out 1000000000 due to readability and typo concerns.

Comment: 1E9 is fine and is the exact same as 1000000000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any cross browser problem with `var x = 1E9;`

No. Scientific notation is a standard for numeric literals and supported everywhere. To increase readability further (and distinguish it from hex), I'd lowercase the e:

```
 var x = 1e9;
```